# Checking positive definiteness on a hyperplane

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-programming

Is there a faster way to check whether $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is positive definite on $b^{\bot}:=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^{n}: x\cdot b=0\}$ than

```
function foo(A,b)
    N = null(b);
    e = eig(N'*A*N);
    return all(e>0);
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of `e = eig(N'*A*N);`, you can use `[R,p]=chol(N'*A*N);`, and test for `p==0`. Matlab function [`chol`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/chol.html) returns the cholesky factor `R` and  a `p` which is zero if `N'*A*N` is positive definite. `p` is a positive integer if the matrix is not positive definite.

Usually `chol` is much faster than `eig`. For example, with dimension `n=2000`, I found that `chol(N'*A*N)` is about  10 times faster than `eig(N'*A*N)` (tested with Octave instead of Matlab).

The matrix product `N'*A*N` is relatively expensive to compute. It might be faster to use a sparse basis `N` for $b^{\bot}$: Matlab/Octave code:

```
function r = foo2(A,b)
    [dummy,p] = sort(abs(b),"descend");
    A = A(p,p);
    m = size(A,1);
    b = b(p);
    N = [b(2:m)/-b(1);speye(m-1,m-1)];   % now b*N = 0
    [L,p] = chol(N'*A*N);
    r = (p==0);
end
```

Comment: That construction of `N` is brilliant. The sparsity is great of course, but I wasn't even aware about that explicit construction.

Comment: (Now that I think of it, it's kind of a super simple version of Gram-Schmidt starting from $(b,e_2,\dots,e_m)$ without the need for an orthogonality nor normality. Still, awesome)

Comment: Note that `N = null(b);` produces an orthogonal `N` (in contrast to the one in `foo2`), which should be preferred if your original matrix `A` is ill conditioned. I haven't looked into the details, but I guess that the matrix `N = [b(2:m)/-b(1);speye(m-1,m-1)];` has a condition number  $\kappa(N) \le \sqrt{m}$.

Comment: For $b \neq 0$ you can easily check the condition number of the sparse `N` with `cond_N = norm(N*b(2:m)'/norm(b(2:m)))`, and decide to use `N = null(b);` if `cond_N` is too large.

Comment: (Note that if the division in `cond_N = norm(N*b(2:m)'/norm(b(2:m)))` fails due to `norm(b(2:m)) == 0`, then `cond_N = 1`.)